# Merge local and remote git repositories containing different files

Tags: git, github, git-merge

So I've made the mistake of pushing a project stored in a local repository on my laptop to GitHub and then made some modifications directly to the files in the remote repository on the website itself. Now I can't pull the files from GitHub and I can't push any changes made in the local repository to the remote because both repos have slightly different files. Is there any way I can merge these two repositories so I can keep on pushing changes from the local to the remote?

Comment: Could you show what "can't pull the files from GitHub" means? Are you getting a conflict?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is, that you have local files, were are changed and are staying in the *working directory*. So first step, just must commit your local changes by using the

```
git commit
```

command. Now you have a empty *working directory* and now you can pull from the remote repo by using the

```
git pull
```

command. This will fetches a new changes and merge them to your local changes. Only there is **no** conflicts (changes in the same file in local and remote version). If there are no conflicts, you can push your changes to remote repo, otherwise you need to resolve all conflicts and then you can also push the changes to the remote repo.

After pushing you will have on both (local and remote) the same version.

Comment: Do you fixed it?

Comment: No, sadly nothing worked. I deleted my local and remote git repos and just started again. I've learned now that you shouldn't updated files pushed to GitHub via git on the website itself. I won't make this mistake again. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

1. `commit` any changes in your local branch (or `reset` them if not required)
2. `fetch` from GitHub to your local repository
3. `merge` the fetched branch (e.g. `origin/master`) into your local branch
4. resolve any conflicts during merge locally
5. `push` your local branch to GitHub

Comment: fetch + merge is the same as a pull, but doing the steps separately does make them less daunting.